# Can I create a button on my site to back up my database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, backup

I want to setup a button in my content management system where I can save a backup sql file for the table shown on a particular page. I just want it to download the SQL file to my computer if this is possible. I also wanted to know if it's possible to do the same thing but export as an excel file of the table data.

If it's easier to just do a backup of the whole database I'd settle for that, I just need to know if it's possible and what it is I'm looking for to build the script.

Hopefully this makes sense, I'm struggling to know what I need to look for as I don't know if it's actually possible. I'm coding in php.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can. But you need to ask something a lot more specific. Do you know how to code an HTML button to trigger a PHP function? Do you know how to connect to a database from PHP? Do you know how to backup a database? Be more specific so we know what we're answering.

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but not really secure. At this point you might as well have [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) (which does that) installed on your server. At least there is an integrated security layer which will be better that what you'll code on your own for a specific case.

Comment: I'm very confident programming in html, css and php. I've got all my connections and various securety methods for multiple accounts on my CMS. This function would be for my personal admin so I would be the only user on it. I'm currently using myphp admin, is there a way to do automatic backups to my server from there? This would be an easier option for me.

Comment: cron (scheduler) mysqlhotcopy (backup) dropbox/email/ftp (storage)

Comment: @huddds, I think your question should be something like "How do I perform a SQL backup like PHPMyAdmin's export function"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a small page enabling you to :

- check the tables you want
- download them
- or write them on disk (server side)

**BUT**

you shouldn't do that if you care about security.

If you want to do this kind of manipulation I recommend you to use [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) instead.

And if you just want to do automatic backups without downloading, you'd better use `cron` and the `mysqldump` command. Cron is configured on many servers to do a backup every night.

Look at this :

http://www.comentum.com/mysqldump-cron.html

http://www.noupe.com/how-tos/10-ways-to-automatically-manually-backup-mysql-database.html

Well. Here's the PHP page :

```
<?

$db_base="set_your_base";
$db=mysql_connect("xxxx","xxxx","xxxx")
or die ("unable to connect");
$select_base=mysql_selectdb($db_base,$db);


function get_para_value($name, $default_value) {
    global $HTTP_GET_VARS, $HTTP_POST_VARS, $_GET, $_POST;
    if( isset($_GET[$name])) {
        return $_GET[$name];
    }
    if( isset($_POST[$name])) {
        return $_POST[$name];
    }
    return $default_value;
}


$action=get_para_value('action', 'ask');

if ($action=='ask') {
    ?>
    <html>
    <body>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    var checkflag = "false";
    function check(form) {
        var objCheckBoxes = form.elements;
        if (checkflag == "false") {
            for (i = 0; i < objCheckBoxes.length; i++) {
                objCheckBoxes[i].checked = true;
            }
            checkflag = "true";
            return "Uncheck all";
        } else {
            for (i = 0; i < objCheckBoxes.length; i++) {
                objCheckBoxes[i].checked = false;
            }
            checkflag = "false";
            return "Check all";
        }
    }
    </script>

    <center>

    <form name=dump_form action=dump_dys.php method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <br>
    Choose the tables you want:
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type=button value="Check all" onClick="this.value=check(this.form)">
    <br>
    <br>
    <table>
    <?php
    $sql_tables = "SHOW TABLES";
    $req_tables = mysql_query($sql_tables);
    while (list($table) = mysql_fetch_row($req_tables)) {
        echo "<tr><td><input type=checkbox name=".$table."> ".$table."</td></tr>";
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    <input type=hidden name=action value=dump>
    <br>
    <input type=button value="Download" onClick="this.form.action.value='dump';this.form.submit();">
    &nbsp; <input type=button value="Write on server" onClick="this.form.action.value='dump_to_disk';this.form.submit();">
    </form>
    </center>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
} else if ($action=='dump') {
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"$db_base.sql\"");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    echo "--\n";
    echo "-- Dump of database $db_base\n";
    echo "--\n";
    $sql_tables = "SHOW TABLES";
    $req_tables = mysql_query($sql_tables);
    while (list($table) = mysql_fetch_row($req_tables)) {
        if (get_para_value($table,'no')=='no') continue;
        echo "\n--\n-- Table $table\n\n";
        echo "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table;\n";
        $sql_create_table = "SHOW CREATE TABLE $table";
        $req_create_table = mysql_query($sql_create_table);
        $create_table = mysql_fetch_array($req_create_table);
        echo $create_table[1].";\n";
        echo "\n--\n-- Filling de $table\n\n";
        $sql_fill_table = "SELECT * FROM $table";
        $req_fill_table = mysql_query($sql_fill_table);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($req_fill_table)) {
        $line_insert = "INSERT INTO $table (";
        $l_value = ") VALUES (";
        foreach ($row as $field => $value) {
            $line_insert .= "`$field`, ";
            $l_value .= "'".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."', ";
        }
        $line_insert = substr($line_insert, 0, -2);
        $l_value = substr($l_value, 0, -2);
        echo $line_insert.$l_value.");\n";
       }
    }

    echo "--\n";
    echo "-- Dump of base $db_base finished )\n";
    echo "--\n";
} else if ($action=='dump_to_disk') {
    $file = fopen($db_base.".sql", 'w') or die('bug!');
    fwrite($file, "--\n");
    fwrite($file,  "-- Dump of the base $db_base\n");
    fwrite($file,  "--\n");
    $sql_tables = "SHOW TABLES";
    $req_tables = mysql_query($sql_tables);
    while (list($table) = mysql_fetch_row($req_tables)) {
        if (get_para_value($table,'no')=='no') continue;
        fwrite($file,  "\n--\n-- Table $table\n\n");
        fwrite($file,  "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table;\n");
        $sql_create_table = "SHOW CREATE TABLE $table";
        $req_create_table = mysql_query($sql_create_table);
        $create_table = mysql_fetch_array($req_create_table);
        fwrite($file,  $create_table[1].";\n");
        fwrite($file,  "\n--\n-- Remplissage de $table\n\n");
        $sql_fill_table = "SELECT * FROM $table";
        $req_fill_table = mysql_query($sql_fill_table);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($req_fill_table)) {
        $line_insert = "INSERT INTO $table (";
        $l_value = ") VALUES (";
        foreach ($row as $field => $value) {
            $line_insert .= "`$field`, ";
            $l_value .= "'".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."', ";
        }
        $line_insert = substr($line_insert, 0, -2);
        $l_value = substr($l_value, 0, -2);
        fwrite($file,  $line_insert.$l_value.");\n");
       }
    }
    fwrite($file, "--\n");
    fwrite($file, "-- Dump of base $db_base finished (not even a crash!)\n");
    fwrite($file, "--\n");
    fclose($file);
    echo "dump done";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm pretty confident in my site security for this area but I may take a look into the myphp admin automated backups. I'll have a play around with this page and consider it a bit more.